# Агрегация и наследование

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование

Можно ли два класса одновременно связать путем агрегации и наследования?

Comment: Более того, есть паттерн проектирования "Декоратор", в котором это используется

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно, можно:

```
class Base
{
};

class Derived: public Base
{
    Base b;
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Derived d;
}
```

Comment: ну как зачем, а вдруг хочется циклического наследования, а это не получается... тут на помощь и приходит агрегация...

Comment: Новогодняя шутка???

Comment: Паттерн Декоратор же!